# why can't I print an object of my own class to the console in Java

Tags: java

I created my own class called Property, and instantiated it. Now I am trying to print out one of its instance to the console, but what's been printed out has been this message shown:
[image]

and this is my code:

```
package playground;

public class PlayGround{
   public static void main(String[] args) {
      Property a = new Property("house",120.2,1989);
      System.out.println(a);  
   } 
}

package playground;

public class Property {
   private String type;
   private double area;
   private int year;
   public Property(String type, double area, int year){
      this.type=type;
      this.area=area;
      this.year=year;
   } 
}
```

Comment: Override the `toString` method with a String representation of your class.

Comment: do you mean I have to create a method in my class called toString() ?

Comment: Yeah, but you should look through the questions that have been linked to from here. They'll provide you with the context and answers you need.

Answer (score 3):

When you use `System.out.println()` method it calls for the Object's `toString()` method. Since you didn't override the default toString method of Object class it calls the default toString method of class Object. You can see the Object's toString method from [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html)

> The toString method for class Object returns a string consisting of
>   the name of the class of which the object is an instance, the at-sign
>   character `@', and the unsigned hexadecimal representation of the hash
>   code of the object. In other words, this method returns a string equal
>   to the value of:

```
getClass().getName() + '@' + Integer.toHexString(hashCode())
```

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.